# Running an executable in R that takes user input

Tags: r, executable

I made some simple code in C to calculate the squared of the number that a user inputs, which can be seen here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int squared(int *x);

int main()
{
    int num = 0;
    printf("Enter an integer: \n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    squared(&num);
    printf("Your number squared is: %d\n",num);

    system("pause");

}

int squared(int *x)
{
    *x *=(*x);
}
```

I would like to call this in R. So I put the executable in my PATH and used `system("Practice.exe")` in RStudio, but this skipped the user input. I do not want to simply call a function in C, as the goal of this is to run an executable with complicated C code so that it can be wrapped in a tcltk gui in R. How can I get user input from an executable in R?

Comment: `system("cat", intern=TRUE, input="world")` and `system2("cat", stdout=TRUE, input="world")` demonstrate how to pass stdin to another program. You can read about them here: [`?system`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/system), [`?system2`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/system2).

Comment: Thank you!! I didn't read the documentation close enough

Comment: I'm a bit bummed to realize that `processx::run`, a method superior in a few ways to `system` and `system2`, does not support stdin at all. Allegedly it is [supported in `processx` in general](https://github.com/r-lib/processx/pull/114/commits/645b08948c8eafc12c1690a1653620c7356b49dd), so it's just a matter of time before [`run()` supports stdin](https://github.com/r-lib/processx/issues/198).